# How to calculate the probability of drawing numbers under certain constrain

Tags: probability-or-statistics

we have number 1,2,3,...n, where n is integer, and we select d distinct numbers from them,$i_{1},i_{2},..i_{d}$.
what's the probability that there exists at least two number difference is greater than k, i.e $|i_{h}-i_{j}|<k$, for any h,j in 1,2,3,...d

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wrong site. You want *Math.Stackexchange*...

Comment: As noted, ask at math.SE. Make sure that when you ask there, you show what you've tried in solving the problem.